# console shows unexpected identifier error and the code doesnot run

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> var movies = [
> {title : "Wolf of wall street" ,stars : 5 , havewatched : false},
> {title : "Mad max fury road" , stars : 5 , havewatched : true},
> {title : "search party " , stars : 5 , havewatched : false} ,
> {title : "brooklyn nine nine" , stars : 5 ,  havewatched : true} ]

```
movies.forEach(function(movie){
   var result = "You have" ;                                                  
   if (movie.havewatched)
     result += "watched" ;
   }else {
      result +=  "not watched";
   }
 result = result + movie.title + "-" + movie.stars ;                                                                                         
 console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code after fixing the missing `{` in the if condition.

```js
var movies = [ {title : "Wolf of wall street" ,stars : 5 , havewatched : false},
{title : "Mad max fury road" , stars : 5 , havewatched : true},
{title : "search party " , stars : 5 , havewatched : false} ,
{title : "brooklyn nine nine" , stars : 5 , havewatched : true} ]

movies.forEach(function(movie){
   var result = "You have" ;                                                  
   if (movie.havewatched){
     result += "watched" ;
   }else {
      result +=  "not watched";
   }
 result = result + movie.title + "-" + movie.stars ;
 console.log(result)
})
```